# Earning in excel file

Tags: otree

This is my first experience with oTree. So I am not entirely sure if this is normal. I am testing my experiment now and while the payoff is showing in the excel data file, I am unable to see the earning. It's not that much of a problem since we just need to divide the payoff by 10. And I want to show both the points as well as the payoff. The code is mentioned below:

```
class Results(Page):
    @staticmethod
    def vars_for_template(player: Player):
        # generate a random outcome as "pchoice"
        # determine whether they can get payoff == whether a random number from [0,1] can be less than 0.5
        pchoice = np.random.random()
        if pchoice <= 0.5:
            player.get_payoff = 1
        else:
            player.get_payoff = 0
        # determine the payoff
        # since get_payoff = 1 or 0, we can multiply directly to get the final payoff
        if player.decision == True:
            player.payoff += C.payment_assetA*player.get_payoff
        if player.decision == False:
            player.payoff += C.payment_assetB*player.get_payoff
        if player.get_payoff == 0:
            player.payoff += C.payment_otherwise
        return dict(
            earning = format(Decimal(player.payoff) / Decimal(10), '.2f')
        )
```

I am not sure if this is normal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My apologies if I wasn't clear enough. What I meant to ask was that the data that I get after testing the experiment does not have any data on the variable named earning. So, I wasn't sure that given my code, if this is normal or should I have written my code differently for the variable to appear in the excel data file.